# Querying json object in dataframe using Pyspark

Tags: python, mysql, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a MySql table with following schema:

```
id-int
path-varchar
info-json {"name":"pat", "address":"NY, USA"....}
```

I used JDBC driver to connect pyspark to MySql. I can retrieve data from mysql using

```
df = sqlContext.sql("select * from dbTable")
```

This query works all fine. My question is, how can I query on "info" column? For example, below query works all fine in MySQL shell and retrieve data but this is not supported in Pyspark (2+).

```
select id, info->"$.name" from dbTable where info->"$.name"='pat'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
res = df.select(get_json_object(df['info'],"$.name").alias('name'))
res = df.filter(get_json_object(df['info'], "$.name") == 'pat')
```

There is already a function named **get_json_object**

---

For your situation:

```
df = spark.read.jdbc(url='jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306', table='test.test_json',
                     properties={'user': 'hive', 'password': '123456'})
df.createOrReplaceTempView('test_json')
res = spark.sql("""
select col_json,get_json_object(col_json,'$.name') from test_json
""")
res.show()
```

Spark sql is almost like HIVE sql, you can see

> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Home

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This method only works when the data is loaded in a data frame. There are hundreds of thousands of records. It might not be efficient way to load the complete table and filter the data against it. Is there way to retrieve the data only matched (json search) with a query rather than loading the complete table?